# syntax error when to join or concat mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrive the mysql result, but my query didn't work because I am new and computer programming or computer database.

```
SELECT guid, post_name
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_parent` = 0 and `post_type` = 'post' and post_title != 'Auto Draft'
```

Returns:

```
guid                    post_name   
http://localhost/?p=21  post-2-title
http://localhost/?p=12  post-4-title
```

And

```
SELECT guid as children_url, post_parent as post_parent
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_parent` != 0 and `post_type` = 'attachment' and post_title != 'Auto Draft'
```

Returns:

```
children_url                               post_parent  
http://localhost/attachment-post-1            12
http://localhost/attachment-post-2            12
http://localhost/attachment-post-3            12
http://localhost/attachment-post-4            12
http://localhost/attachment-post-5            12
http://localhost/attachment-post-6            12
http://localhost/attachment-post-7            12
http://localhost/attachment-post-8            12
http://localhost/attachment-post-9            21
http://localhost/attachment-post-10           21
http://localhost/attachment-post-11           21
http://localhost/attachment-post-12           21
http://localhost/attachment-post-13           21
http://localhost/attachment-post-14           21
http://localhost/attachment-post-15           21
http://localhost/attachment-post-16           21
```

I have tried several query but didn't succeed,

```
SELECT guid as children_url, post_parent as post_parent
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_parent` != 0 and `post_type` = 'attachment' and post_title != 'Auto Draft'
  and SELECT guid, post_name FROM `wp_posts`
      WHERE `post_parent` = 0 and `post_type` = 'post' and post_title != 'Auto Draft'
```

Raises the error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT guid, post_name FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_parent` = 0
>   and `post_type` =' at line 1

What I want the result like :

```
 children_url                              post_parent              post_paraent_guid       post_parent_title
http://localhost/attachment-post-1            12                    http://localhost/?p=12  post-2-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-2            12                    http://localhost/?p=12  post-2-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-3            12                    http://localhost/?p=12  post-2-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-4            12                    http://localhost/?p=12  post-2-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-5            12                    http://localhost/?p=12  post-2-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-6            12                    http://localhost/?p=12  post-2-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-7            12                    http://localhost/?p=12  post-2-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-8            12                    http://localhost/?p=12  post-2-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-9            21                    http://localhost/?p=21  post-4-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-10           21                    http://localhost/?p=21  post-4-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-11           21                    http://localhost/?p=21  post-4-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-12           21                    http://localhost/?p=21  post-4-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-13           21                    http://localhost/?p=21  post-4-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-14           21                    http://localhost/?p=21  post-4-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-15           21                    http://localhost/?p=21  post-4-title
http://localhost/attachment-post-16           21                    http://localhost/?p=21  post-4-title
```

Any help would appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: You want four columns, and asking for only two columns. Or did I just misread your question?

Comment: you are right, I am sorry because of my limited knowledge about database query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    pc.guid as children_url,
    pc.post_parent as post_parent,
    pp.guid as post_paraent_guid,
    pp.post_title as post_parent_title
FROM
    wp_posts pc
    left join wp_posts pp on pp.ID=pc.post_parent
WHERE
    pc.post_type = 'attachment'
    and pc.post_title != 'Auto Draft'
ORDER BY
    pc.guid
```

Comment: anyway also how to limit retrieve from only categoryId 2?

Comment: add where condition `WHERE
    pc.post_type = 'attachment'
    and pc.post_title != 'Auto Draft' and categoryId=2`

Comment: I am sorry but Unknown column 'categoryId' in 'where clause', I use wordpress database

Comment: I don't have wordpress DB, so I can't say how it is organized